# Create vector .shp file and draw several lines with various attributes (L, Z, S%, etc) from coordinates pairs

Tags: python, shapefile, osgeo

I have a set or coordinates which forms lines from  two points (p1-p2, p2-p3,...., p(n-1)-p(n)), I want to create a SHP file in order to draw several lines from these points, which have several features (Length, Slope, Velocity, etc).

So far, I have been able to create the shape file and create fields, but I can not manage to fill these fields or create a geometry lines to associate with.
Can anybody point me to an example  to successfully draw lines on a shapefile using a foor loop, because coordinates points  are in the order of magnitude of 10^2.

```
#IMPORTAR LIBRERIAS
import ogr,os
import osgeo.osr as osr

#DRIVERNAME
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ds = driver.CreateDataSource("PROYECTO_" + shp_name + os.path.sep + "00_GIS" + os.path.sep + "00_IN" + os.path.sep + shp_name + '.shp')

#REFERENCIA ESPACIAL
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(32717) #WGS84 17S

#CREAR SHAPE de PUNTOS (ogr.wbkPoint) O LINEA (ogr.wkbLineString)
if shp_type == "linea":
    layer = ds.CreateLayer(shp_name, srs, ogr.wkbLineString)
if shp_type == "punto":
    layer = ds.CreateLayer(shp_name, srs, ogr.wkbPoint)

#AGREGAR CAMPOS
#NOMBRE TRAMO (Numero o Caracter)
fieldDefn = ogr.FieldDefn('Ramal', ogr.OFTString)
layer.CreateField(fieldDefn)

#NOMBRE TIPO DE ALCANTARILLADO (Sanitario, Pluvial, Combinado)
fieldDefn = ogr.FieldDefn('Tipo', ogr.OFTString)
layer.CreateField(fieldDefn)

# NOMBRE TIPO DE ALCANTARILLADO (Sanitario, Pluvial, Combinado)
fieldDefn = ogr.FieldDefn('Material', ogr.OFTString)
layer.CreateField(fieldDefn)

# LONGITUD
fieldDefn = ogr.FieldDefn('Longitud', ogr.OFTString)
layer.CreateField(fieldDefn)
```

Answer (score 1):

For each pair of coordinates:

1. Create geometry object and add each coordinate [(see here)](https://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/geometry.html).
2. Create a feature object, set the geometry object and any attribute info, add it to the layer ([similar to here](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/97854/osgeo.ogr.Feature))

Comment: Hi Nick, thank you for the guidance. I will post my result code for anyone with the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Thank to Nick's answer i was able to get a working code for drawing multiples lines from a coordinates set, not sure if it is efficient but it works.

```
 coords = [(0, 0), (0, 10), (10, 0)]
```

def shp_out(coords):

```
# IMPORTAR LIBRERIAS
import ogr
import osgeo.osr as osr

# DRIVERNAME
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
ds = driver.CreateDataSource('OUT.shp')

# REFERENCIA ESPACIAL
srs = osr.SpatialReference()
srs.ImportFromEPSG(32717)  # WGS84 17S

# CREAR SHAPE LINEA (ogr.wkbLineString)
layer = ds.CreateLayer(shp_name, srs, ogr.wkbLineString)

# AGREGAR CAMPOS
# NOMBRE TRAMO (Numero o Caracter)
fieldDefn = ogr.FieldDefn('FIELD_1', ogr.OFTString)
layer.CreateField(fieldDefn)
line = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
for i in range(len(coords)-1):



    line.AddPoint(coords[i][0], coords[i][1])
    line.AddPoint(coords[i + 1][0], coords[i + 1][0])

    #ADD FIELD
    feature = ogr.Feature(layer.GetLayerDefn())
    feature.SetField("FIELD_1", 'VALUE1')
    feature.SetGeometry(line)

    # Create the feature in the layer (geojson)
    layer.CreateFeature(feature)
    # Destroy the feature to free resources
    feature.Destroy()
```

or if you wan to have a different line for each data point pair, (REALLY bad idea to use globlas for this, but I can not figure it out any other way).

```
    for i in range(len(coords) - 1):
         globals()["line" + str(i)] = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbLineString)
         globals()["line" + str(i)].AddPoint(coords[i][0], coords[i][1])
         globals()["line" + str(i)].AddPoint(coords[i + 1][0], coords[i + 1][0])

        feature = ogr.Feature(layer.GetLayerDefn())
        for j in range(len(campos)):
             feature.SetField(campos[j], 'VALUE2')
        feature.SetGeometry(globals()["line" + str(i)])

        # Create the feature in the layer (geojson)
        layer.CreateFeature(feature)
        # Destroy the feature to free resources
        feature.Destroy()
        globals()["line" + str(i)].Destroy()
```